# What is the difference between FallbackValue and TargetNullValue in UWP and WinUI3?

Tags: xaml, uwp, winui-3

can someone please tell me the exact difference between `FallbackValue` and `TargetNullValue`? I know they are quite similar, but I'd like to understand more about those edge usecases where you want to use **either one of the two** or maybe usecases where **using both** makes sense.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically,

- `FallbackValue` is set when the binding itself fails.
- `TargetNullValue` is set when the source of the binding is **null**.

These are the results I got with WinUI 3.

**Plain binding**

```cs
public string TestText { get; set; } = "Binding succeeded!";
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestText}" />
  OR
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestText}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows "Binding succeeded".

**Case#1**
`x:Bind`, `FallbackValue`/`TargetNullValue`, wrong name

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = "Binding succeeded!";
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Test, FallbackValue='Binding failed!'}" />
  OR
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Test, TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

You get a compile error because `x:Bind` checks the source at compile time.

**Case#2**
`x:Bind`, `FallbackValue`, null source

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestText, FallbackValue='Binding failed!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows nothing (empty).

**Case#3**
`Binding`, `FallbackValue`, wrong name

```cs
public string TestText { get; set; } = "Binding successed!";
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Test, FallbackValue='Binding failed!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows the `FallbackValue` "Binding failed!".

**Case#4**
`x:Bind`, `TargetNullValue`, null source

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestText, TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows the `TargetNullValue` "Source is null!".

**Case#5**
`Binding`, `TargetNullValue`, null source

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestText, TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows nothing (empty).

**Case#6**
`Binding`, `FallbackValue`, `TargetNullValue`, null source

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestText, FallbackValue='Binding failed!', TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows the `FallbackValue` "Binding failed!".

**Case#7**
`x:Bind`, `FallbackValue`, `TargetNullValue`, null source

```cs
public string? TestText { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind TestText, FallbackValue='Binding failed!', TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows the `TargetNullValue` "Source is null!".

**Case#8**
`x:Bind`/`Binding`, `TargetNullValue`, null **ViewModel**

```cs
public ViewModel? ViewModel { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestText, TargetNullValue='Source is null!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows nothing (empty).

**Case#9**
`x:Bind`/`Binding`, `FallbackValue`, null **ViewModel**

```cs
public ViewModel? ViewModel { get; set; } = null;
```

```xml
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.TestText, FallbackValue='Binding failed!'}" />
```

The `TextBlock` shows the `FallbackValue` "Binding failed!".

Comment: Wow, what a perfectly detailed answer! Thanks!

I think one usecase is missing, what if I x:Bind to `MyViewModel.TestText`, but the `MyViewModel` is null here? Will it use the TargetNullValue or FallbackValue?

Comment: Updated my answer. It fails to bind.